# Simple proof for uniqueness of solutions of linear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system of linear ODEs $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$, $x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Does anyone know a simple proof showing that the solutions are unique that does not require resorting to more general existence/uniqueness results (e.g., those relating to the Picard iteration) nor solving for the solutions explicitly?

Comment: Note that having an explicit solution only shows existence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just need uniqueness, use the Bellman-Gronwall lemma. Suppose $x,y$ are two solutions, then $x(0) = y(0) = x_0$, and both $x,y$ satisfy the ODE. In particular, if we let $\delta = x-y$, we have $\delta(t) = \int_0^t A \delta(\tau) d\tau$, and hence $\|\delta(t)\| \leq \int_0^t \|A\|  |\delta(\tau)\| d\tau$, from which it follows (using the integral form of the Bellman-Gronwall lemma) that $\|\delta(t)\| = 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks - that works fine. I'm not accepting it yet though because I'm looking for one to hand out the some undergrad engineering students who are not familiar with matrix norms.

Answer (score 4):

Since the students are engineers, why don't you want to show them explicit solutions, which surely they'd need to see anyway?  If we *knew* about a matrix exponential $e^{At}$, then to show $x(t) = e^{At}x_0$ let's look at the $t$-derivative of $e^{-At}x(t)$, which is 
$$
e^{-At}x'(t) + (-Ae^{-At})x(t) = e^{-At}Ax(t) - Ae^{-At}x(t).
$$
From the series definition of the matrix exponential, $A$ and $e^{Bt}$ commute if $A$ and $B$ commute, so $A$ and $e^{-At}$ commute. Thus
$$
(e^{-At}x(t))' = e^{-At}Ax(t) - Ae^{-At}x(t) = Ae^{-At}x(t) - Ae^{-At}x(t) = 0.
$$
Therefore $e^{-At}x(t)$ is a constant vector, and setting $t = 0$ tells us this constant vector has to be $x(0) = x_0$. Thus $e^{-At}x(t) = x_0$, so $x(t) = e^{At}x_0$ if we know that $e^{At}$ and $e^{-At}$ are inverses of each other.

Note that this solution can be thought of as a higher-dimensional version of the integration-free proof that the only solution of the 1-dim. ODE $y'(t) = ay(t)$ with $y(0) = y_0$ is $y_0e^{at}$: if $y(t)$ is a solution then the derivative of $e^{-at}y(t)$ is
$$
e^{-at}y'(t) - ae^{-at}y(t) = e^{-at}(ay(t)) - ae^{-at}y(t) = 0.
$$
Thus $e^{-at}y(t)$ is a constant function, and at $t = 0$ we see the value is $y(0) = y_0$, so $e^{-at}y(t) = y_0$. Thus $y(t) = y_0e^{at}$. In higher dimensions we just need to be more careful about the order of multiplication (e.g., the way the product rule is formulated for matrix-valued functions).

Comment: If a vector function $y(t)$ has $t$-derivative 0 then it is a constant vector (I assume the $t$-domain is an interval). So, granting the properties of matrix exponentials, the argument implies that the only possible solution is $e^{At}x(0) = e^{At}x_0$. Why do you think the argument doesn't prove $e^{At}x_0$ is the only solution?

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread. The initial idea was getting them to prove $\frac{d}{dt}e^{At} = Ae^{At}$, using that to verify that $x(t)=e^{At}x_0$ is indeed a solution, i.e., that $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$ and $x(0)=x_0$ and hopefully finishing it of with a brief uniqueness proof. The only extra effort the your suggestion requires is showing that $A$ and $e^{Bt}$ commute  if $A$ and $B$ commute, which is probably the best I could hope for.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'd suggest for the students that you place side-by-side the one-dimensional argument and then the higher-dimensional one, so that they see it is essentially the same idea except for being a bit fussier about the order of multiplication. In fact the way I came up with the solution I posted is by starting with the solution in the one-dimensional case and turning scalars there into either vectors or matrices as needed.

Comment: I did, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution of the initial value problem $X'=AX$ with $X(0)=X_0$ is    $$X(t)=e^{At}X_0$$ Let $Y(t)$ be an another solution satisfying  $Y(0)=X_0$. I want to show that $X(t)=Y(t)$. Define $$Z(t)=exp(-tA)\cdot Y(t)$$ $$\qquad\frac{dZ}  {dt}=-\exp(-tA)\cdot Y(t)+\exp(-tA)\cdot Y(t) =0$$ therefore $Z(t)$ is a constant. Setting $t=0$ we have $Z(t)=X_0$ so  $Y(t)=\exp(At)X_0$ with  $Y(0)=X_0$ this completes the proof.

Comment: Ok. There are a lot of misunderstandings about formulas here. This is a main problem, Maisam.

Comment: i modify it isit true?