# Find the dimension of $V = \{f \in C^k [0, 1] : a_n f^{(n)}(t)+\cdots+a_0 f (t) = 0 \textrm{ for all } t \in [0, 1]\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Using the additive properties of differentiation I proved that $V$ is a subspace. The fact that $\overline{O} \in V$ is also trivial. However, I am stuck as to how to use the property of the continuity and differentiability of $f \in V$ to find out the dimension of $V$.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The $a_i$ from $i = 0$ to $i = n $ are fixed and are $\in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Try to see what happens for $n = 0$ and $n=1$. What do you get there? Also, please be more clear: opy the definition of the space into the question and explain what the $a_n$ are (do they have to exist? are they fixed?) etc.

Comment: If $a_i=0$ for all $i$ then $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: This is question from ODE. The solution set of a DE of order $n$ with constant coefficients  has $n$ linearly independent solutions. So the answer is $n$ if $a_n \neq 0$.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this problem without knowing ODE. The thing is we have this question in our linear algebra course, so that's why I am a bit a curious.

Comment: It is unlikely that you are expected to "prove" that the dimension of this space is $n$, but perhaps the instructor expects you to "guess" that this is the answer. If you are curious how one might directly prove that the dimension $n$, we could use one of ideas [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284061/81360)

Comment: Does this thread answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408959/?  (Or does it create more confusion?)