# Why is $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$ the only solution family to $a\cdot f''(x)+b\cdot f'(x)+c\cdot f(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was taught that $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$ is the only solution family to $a\cdot f''(x)+b\cdot f'(x)+c\cdot f(x)=0$ (provided that $b^2-4ac\neq0$).

Here is my teacher's proof showing why:

---

Assume that $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda$. Then the differential equation becomes:

$$a\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{\lambda x}+b\frac{d}{dx}e^{\lambda x}+ce^{\lambda x}=0$$
$$a\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}+b\lambda e^{\lambda x}+ce^{\lambda x}=0$$
$$e^{\lambda x}(a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c)=0$$
$$a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$$
Then if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the roots of the equation $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$, $f(x)=e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and $f(x)=e^{\lambda_2 x}$ are solutions to the differential equation.

Now suppose $g(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation, then we can show $C\cdot g(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation where $C$ is a real number:

$$aC\cdot g''(x)+bC\cdot g'(x)+cC\cdot g(x)=0$$
$$C(a\cdot g''(x)+b\cdot g'(x)+c\cdot g(x)=0)$$
$$a\cdot g''(x)+b\cdot g'(x)+c\cdot g(x)=0$$

which is true by definition. Therefore we know $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and $f(x)=C_2e^{\lambda_2 x}$ are solution sets for real $C_1, C_2$.

We can also show $f_1(x)+f_2(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation provided that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ satisfy the equation:

$$a(f_1(x)+f_2(x))''+b(f_1(x)+f_2(x))'+c(f_1(x)+f_2(x))=0$$
$$a(f_1''(x)+f_2''(x))+b(f_1'(x)+f_2'(x))+c(f_1(x)+f_2(x))=0$$
$$a\cdot f_1''(x)+b\cdot f_1'(x)+c\cdot f_1(x)+a\cdot f_2''(x)+b\cdot f_2''(x)+c\cdot f_2''(x)=0$$
$$a\cdot f_1''(x)+b\cdot f_1'(x)+c\cdot f_1(x)=0, a\cdot f_2''(x)+b\cdot f_2''(x)+c\cdot f_2''(x)=0$$
both of which are true by definition. Therefore $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$ is a solution family to the differential equation (the only exception being when $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$).

---

However, there is an issue with this proof: it merely shows that $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$ is *a* solution family, but it does not show that $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$ is *the only* solution family. In other words, the proof does not show that there are solutions to the equation not of the form $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$.

My question is: How can we show that $f(x)=C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$ is the only solution family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer this second order ODE to a first order ODE and then use the theory for first order ODEs. If $a = 0$, you have a first order ODE right away. So assume $a \neq 0$. Now, if you set $g = f'$, your second order ODE is equivalent to this first order ODE:
$$\begin{pmatrix} f' \\ g' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\frac{c}{a} & -\frac{b}{a} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} f \\ g \end{pmatrix}.$$
The uniqueness then follows from the uniqueness of first order ODEs, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284061/simple-proof-for-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-linear-odes).

Comment: You explained the second step, but not the first. With the given solution family one can realize any set of initial conditions. Uniqueness then tells that this is indeed the only solution to this IVP.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Fair enough, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have a question. The link only shows the uniqueness of equations of the form $y'=Ay$, but our equations are $f'=g$ and $g'=-\frac caf-\frac bag$. Don't we need to show that $g=Cf$ for some constant $C$?

Comment: Also, why do we have to represent the equations as the product of two matrices, instead of directly representing it?

Comment: @Kyky $f$ and $g$ are the two coordinates of $y$ in this case (not different solutions of the ODE), i.e., $y_1 = f$ and $y_2 = g$. The matrix is used to transfer your second order ODE to a (vector valued) first order ODE, which is easier to deal with. It is a common trick in the study of linear ODEs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. That clears things up.